# fprintf give me a blank file in c

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to store some data from a GPS to a txt file. The problem is that first the .txt file was empty after y stop the program, but know, when I run the code is like it enter to an infinite bucle and doesn't print me data on screen or in .txt file.

```
char add_aux_XS[50],file_name_XS[256],file_txt_name_XS[256];
FILE *Ublox_text;

char * txt_file_UB() {
    printf("Name of txt file (include extension txt): \n");

    scanf("%s",file_name_UB);

    strcpy(add_aux_UB,"/home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/gps/");

    sprintf(add_UB,"%s%s",add_aux_UB,file_name_UB); 

    return add_UB;
}

main()
{
    file_txt_UB=txt_file_UB();
    for(i=0;i<256;i++){file_txt_name_UB[i]=*(file_txt_UB+i);}
    Ublox_text=fopen(file_txt_name_UB,"w");
    fprintf(Ublox_text,"\n");

    Ublox_UART=Conf_Ublox();
    while(1)
    {
        struct UBLOX_message Read_UB=Reading_UBLOX(Ublox_UART);
        printf("Valid: %c \t lat: %lf \t lon: %lf \t north: %lf \t east: %lf \n",
            Read_UB.valid,Read_UB.lat,Read_UB.lon,Read_UB.north,Read_UB.east);

        fprintf(Ublox_text,"%c \t %lf \t %lf \t %lf \t %lf \n",
            Read_UB.valid,Read_UB.lat,Read_UB.lon,Read_UB.north,Read_UB.east); 
    }       
    fclose(Ublox_text);     
    close_Ublox();
}
```

When I comment the `fprintf` line, the program is OK and print in screen the sensor values.

Comment: Copying an uninitialized string over itself with `for(i=0;i<256;i++){file_txt_name_UB[i]=*(file_txt_UB+i);}` does not actually initialize it usefully.  Your `text_file_UB()` function is using all sorts of undefined variables — that's not good.  You need to read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and then edit your question so it becomes one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straight forward to me - you have an infinite `while (1)` loop, so it will never end.

If you abort the program, all the buffered writes are *discarded*, as the `fclose` was never reached.

You can add a `fflush()` inside the loop, to get it written every time, but that will slow things down considerably (there is a reason why the OS normally buffers all your writing). But the better solution is to correct the infinite loop, so it ends at some point in time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I need to read the GPS constantly during the test, and I dont know how long can be the test it can be one minute as it can be one hour, that's why I use and infinite loop.

Comment: Slowing things down might not be a bad thing. If `Reading_UBLOX()` is fast, you'll get a *lot* of output. Try adding `fflush(Ublox_text)` in the loop and see what happens. If that slows things down too much, consider calling `fflush()` once for every N iterations.

Comment: @JuanBravo: How will your program know when the test is over?  You don't seem to check the value returned by `Reading_UBLOX()`, which means you aren't paying attention to any errors it reports, or normal events like EOF.  As it stands, your program has to be sent death threats (signals, like interrupts) for it to stop.  Hardly elegant.